# get fd of terminal when a destination of pipe

Tags: c, terminal, posix

My program (a text editor) enters raw mode of terminal like this:

```
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw)
```

so that it can read key strokes, draw using escape codes etc.

But now I want to do this: `echo hello | myprog`, to read stdin from a pipe and then display it in the program UI. But now STDIN_FILENO points to a pipe not to a terminal and `tcsetattr` fails with `improper ioctl`. How do I get `fd` of an actual terminal when being a destination of a pipe?

Comment: Check [`isatty`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) first.

Comment: Without research, you probably need to follow chain of parent processes, until you find one with a pty. Then hijack that.

Comment: How would you expect `cat | myprog` to function?

Comment: @hyde `cat|myprog` will fail, but does it matter I should give up the idea? try `echo hello | vi` or `echo hello | less` they support it.

Comment: If you're within a pipe and are _not_ the _first_ in a chain, you shouldn't mess with the user TTY input. That's the purview of the first child in the pipe [or the invoking shell] but not your program. So, check with `isatty` and do _not_ do ioctls if your `stdin` is _not_ a TTY.

Comment: Those examples are for TTY _output_ and _not_ input. BTW, `echo hello | less` is fine but `echo hello | vi` is often a disaster.

Comment: @CraigEstey I am basically writing an analog to `less` to display stdin with some UI that support page up/down etc, what you say means that terminal is not supposed to be used like that in the first place.

Comment: And, depending upon what _you_ mean by "raw" mode, just doing a flush isn't what I would call entering raw mode. You normally grab the TTY parameters, turn off `ECHO`, `ICANON`, `VMIN = 0`, `VTIM = 0`, etc. and then set that mode (e.g. `cfmakeraw`).

Comment: You could/should look at what `less` does, but, you could check `stdout`. If it's _not_ a TTY, then `less` is just a pass through like `cat`. If it _is_ a TTY, but `stdin` is a pipe, you may need to open `/dev/tty` and get raw input from there.

Comment: @CraigEstey I just figured few minutes ago I could use `fileno(fopen("/dev/tty", "rw"))`. Thanks for the `cfmakeraw` hint, I am not only using `TCAFLUSH` also set some flags, the code was just taken from kilo tutorial years ago. https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo

Comment: Instead of: `int fdtty = fileno(fopen("/dev/tty", "rw"))` how about: `int fdtty = open("/dev/tty",O_RDWR);` Note that as you're using `fopen`, the `FILE *` pointer is lost, so you can't do `fclose`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, `/dev/tty` is the current console, and if you don't need stdio interfaces, you can open it, receiving a fd, with `int ttyfd = open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)`. (It's usually a bad idea to mix Unix I/O and stdio I/O on the same device. But if you really want to, open with `FILE* ftty = fopen("/dev/tty", "rw");` and get the fd out of the `FILE*` with `fileno(ftty)`.)